# Block matrix characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, characteristic-polynomial

Let $n \in \Bbb N^*$ and $A \in \cal M_n(\Bbb R)$ a square matrix.  Let the block matrix

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}A&A\\A&A \end{pmatrix} \in \cal M_{2n}(\Bbb R)$$

1. Calculate the  characteristic polynomial $\chi_B$ using $\chi_A$.
2. Proof that $A$ is diagonalisable $\iff$ $B$ is diagonalisable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part: we have
$$
tI_{2n} - B = 
\pmatrix{tI_n - A & -A\\ -A & tI_n - A}
$$
Noting that these matrices commute (or in particular, that the lower two matrices commute), we have
$$
\begin{align}
\det(tI_{2n} - B) &= \det((tI_n - A)^2-A^2)\\
&= \det[((tI_n - A)-A)((tI_n - A)+A)]\\
&= \det((tI_n - A)-A) \det((tI_n - A)+A)\\
&= \det((tI_n - 2A) \det(tI_n)\\
&= \det(2((t/2) - A)) \det(tI_n)\\
&= 2^n \det((t/2) - A) t^n\\
&= 2^n t^n \chi_A\left(\frac t2\right)
\end{align}
$$

Second part: I haven't put it all together nicely, but here are some potentially helpful thoughts

**Thought 1:** If $B$ is diagonalizable, then $B$ has $2n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.  Now, let
$$
v = \pmatrix{v_1\\v_2}
$$
be an eigenvector of $B$, with $v_1,v_2 \in \mathbb{C}^n$.  What can we say about the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$?  Remember that $B$ has the eigenvector $0$ of multiplicity $n + \operatorname{null}(A)$.

**Thought 2:**
$$
\pmatrix{I & I\\ I& -I} \pmatrix{A & A\\ A & A}\pmatrix{I& I\\I & -I} = 
\pmatrix{4A & 0\\0 & 0}
$$
Or, in particular,
$$
\frac{1}{2}\pmatrix{I & I\\ I& -I} \pmatrix{A & A\\ A & A} 
\pmatrix{I& I\\I & -I} = \\
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{I & I\\ I& -I}\right)^{-1} \pmatrix{A & A\\ A & A} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{I& I\\I & -I} =
\pmatrix{2A & 0\\0 & 0}
$$

Comment: Thank's, Omnomnomnom, for this answer.It's for me of considerable interest. 
I have an answer in which I use matrix direct product. 
if $ J = \begin {pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\1 & 1 \end {pmatrix} $, 
then $ J \otimes A = B =\begin{pmatrix}A&A\\A&A\end{pmatrix}$. 
We have $ J \sim D $ where $ D = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\0 & 2 \end {pmatrix} $ and
this follows that $ J \otimes A \sim D \otimes A = \begin {pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\0 & 2A \end {pmatrix} $.
 I notice that it looks like the last part of your answer.
 Can we find  a link between the two?

Comment: Yes, there's a link. Note that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{I & I\\ I&I}$ is its own inverse.  Thus, taking my last answer and dividing by $2$ on both sides gives you a proof of similarity.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that matrix wrong.  At any rate, I've edited the end of my answer; take a look.